# Get Data from JSON File in Angular2 in VS2017

Tags: angular, json.net, angular2-services, angular2-observables

Am able to get the data from JSON file and displaying in Html component by using services.The issues am facing is i need to display first data from Json and after clicking on next button need to display the next data. like the quiz application.
Below my code
Services.ts code

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionServices {

    private _url = './app/question.json';
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }


    getQuestions(): Observable<any> {
        //debugger;
        return this._http.get('./app/question.json')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());      
    }
}
```

question.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-question',
    // templateUrl: 'template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");',
    styleUrls: ['app/user.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'app/question.component.html',
    providers: [UserServices,QuestionServices]
})

export class UserList {
    data: Observable<Array<any>>;

    Questions: Observable<Array<any>>;
    Question: Observable<any>;
    options: Observable<Array<any>>;

    private _url = 'app/question.json';


    constructor(private services: QuestionServices) {
        //this.data = services.getQuestions();
       // console.log("Appcomponent.data:"+this.data);
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        //debugger;
        this.data = this.services.getQuestions();
        console.log("Enter into section 1", this.data);

    }


}
```

Json File:

```
[
  {
    "Qno": 1,
    "QuestionText": "Which of the following object is ideal for keeping data alive for a single request?",
    "QuestionType": "radio",
    "Options": [
      {
        "name": "HttpContext",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Session",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "Qno": 2,
    "QuestionText": "Which of the following does NOT require type casting?",
    "QuestionType": "dropdown",
    "Options": [
      {
        "name": "Session",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "ViewBag",
        "value": 2
      }
    ]

  },
  {
    "Qno": 3,
    "QuestionText": "Which are the cities you have gone?",
    "QuestionType": "checkbox",
    "Options": [
      {
        "name": "Chennai",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Bangalore",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Mysore",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Delhi",
        "value": 2
      }

    ]

  },
  {
    "Qno": 4,
    "QuestionText": "Enter name",
    "QuestionType": "textbox"
  }
]
```

Html Component code

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data | async;">
    <div *ngIf="d.QuestionType=='radio'">
        <div> Question: {{d.Qno}} </div>
        <div>{{d.QuestionText}}</div>
        <form *ngFor="let opt of d.Options">
            <input type="radio" value={{opt.Value}} name="radiogroup">{{opt.name}}
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div *ngIf="d.QuestionType=='dropdown'">
        <div> Question: {{d.Qno}} </div>
        <div>{{d.QuestionText}}</div>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option *ngFor="let opt of d.Options">
                    {{opt.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div *ngIf="d.QuestionType=='checkbox'">
        <div> Question: {{d.Qno}} </div>
        <div>{{d.QuestionText}}</div>
        <form *ngFor="let opt of d.Options">
            <input type="checkbox" name="city" value={{opt.name}}>{{opt.name}}
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div *ngIf="d.QuestionType=='textbox'">
        <div> Question: {{d.Qno}} </div>
        <div>{{d.QuestionText}}:<input type="text" /></div>

    </div>
</div>
<button>Load Next Question</button>
```

The point is when clicking on the next button i need to display the next question from the Json file. now its displaying all the questions.
any idea for achieving this.

Comment: this is something in which you need to take help of css to use display property to have only one item displayed in the ngFor

Comment: by using the Index is possible to populate the next question.@RahulSingh

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple set up like this and add up using CSS

**Component**

```
  counter = 0;
  next(){
    if(this.data.length-1 > this.counter) {
          this.counter ++ ;
          alert(this.counter);
    }

  }
```

**Template**

```
<div>
   {{data[counter]}}
  </div> 

  <button (click) = "next()"> Next </button>
```

[**`Working Link`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mycounter)

It is not full prof as you still have to check for counter if it exceeds the array length but i think you can tweak that

Comment: at first time load how display the first question.

Comment: in ngOnInit() set the counter to 0 and by default the value should be -1

Comment: and i think this by default shows the first question only ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by storing a variable that holds a position, defaulting to 0, and make the next button increment this number - something like:

```
<button (click)="position++">next</button>
```

Now in your question template, save the index when stepping through the json:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data | async; let i = index">
```

Finally add a test to see if `index` matches `position`, and only display that question if true:

```
<div *ngIf="i == position">
```

Comment: <div *ngIf="index == position"> have to replace index into i.
<div *ngIf="i== position">

Comment: Yep - fixed typo.